# How to do Subquery for same Table in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have structured a categories table to store Categories as well as Sub Categories.

My table Structure is:

```
catID (int)
catType (varchar 4)
parentID (int)
catName (varchar 50)
sOrder (int)
```

How to do following subquery with Eloquent.

```
SELECT c.*, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories AS sc WHERE sc.parentID = c.catID AND sc.catType = "Sub" 
) AS totalSubCategories
FROM categories AS c 
WHERE c.catType = 'Root'
```

I have tried following but it wont work:

```
$rows = CategoryModel::from('categories as c')
        ->where('c.catType', '=', 'Root')
        ->paginate(20)
        ->select(DB::raw('c.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories as sc WHERE sc.parentID = c.catID AND sc.catType = "Sub") AS totalCategories'));
```

I am getting following Error

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'select'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an Eloquent relationship on the same table, and filter it to the right `catType`:

```
public function children() {
  return $this->hasMany('Model', 'parentID')->where('catType', 'Sub');
}
```

This makes the item's children available as `$item->children`. You can get a count like so:

```
$count = $item->children()->count();
```